# How to treat to attribute selector:hover

Tags: css, attributes, hover

[image]Im new with css, Im one of our homework in class is to make a box with 4 imgs, that while im mouse hover image it will be bigger in the center of the box.

each image must be with 2 files, small one will start with th and the big one start with big. need to practice the attribute selector.

so I make something, but I just cant fiqure why its not working.

```css
 body>div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      border: 2px solid black;

    }

    div {
      position: relative;
    }



    div>div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 400px;
    }



    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 20px 10px;
    }

    img[src*="th"] {
      width: 250px;
      border: 3px solid black;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666;
    }

    img[src*="/big"] {
      display:none;
    }

    img[src*="th"]:hover {
      box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #666;

    }

    img[src*="th"]:hover+img[src*="/big"] {
      display:block;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
 <div>

    <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/thCar.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/thHome.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/thTree.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/thPlane.jpg" alt="">
    <div>
      <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/bigCar.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/bigHome.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/bigTree.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/bigPlane.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it by keeping the imgs next to each other.
The "+" works for next sibling element only.

```css
.outer-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.outer-div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}

img[src*="/100"] {
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666;
}

img[src*="/200"] {
  display: none;
}

img[src*="/100"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #666;
}

img[src*="/100"]:hover+img[src*="/200"] {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">

  <div class="inner-div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `+`-selector select an element that is directly after another element.

Therefor your big image div must be directly next to the smaller image. And you have use this selector `img[src*="th"]:hover+div img[src*="/big"]` instead of `img[src*="th"]:hover+img[src*="/big"]` to address the nested image.

```css
body>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 400px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

img[src*="th"] {
  width: 250px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #666;
}

img[src*="/big"] {
  display: none;
}

img[src*="th"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #666;
}

img[src*="th"]:hover+div img[src*="/big"] {
  display: block;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div>

  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x50/f00&text=/th" alt="">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/f00&text=/big" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x50&text=/th" alt="">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200&text=/big" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x50/0f0&text=/th" alt="">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/0f0&text=/big" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/thPlane.jpg" alt="">
  <div>
    <img src="/HTML/HW/HW27_5/bigPlane.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, there’s a way to select the relevant image without changing the HTML format , the big ones in any with with attribute selector?

Comment: @IdanBachar Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You say the + is for sibling elect only right? So that means that I need to change the positions of the divs. There’s any way to still get what I want and select the “big “ image without changing the HTML? Maybe with different way to select the element after the :hover?

Comment: No this, is not possible with CSS. You always want to select the corresponding large image, right? Then you need a selector that truly selects only one image. Therefore you must always take the next or a child element. Maybe you can take a look at the [`~`-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp), but then all following big images will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Mission completed and I got the point that is the must important thing!